# Get the shipping method of each order for a customer

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get a list of all the shipping methods a customer (by ID) has chosen for each order.

So if a customer has made 3 orders, I want to return:

```
  1)  Check / Money
  2)  Credit card
  3)  Check / Money
```

(For example)

I am getting lost in the resource models and collections...

I tried this:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

    foreach ($orderCollection as $_order){
        $shipping_method = $_order->getShippingMethod(); 
    }
```

But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in below way:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
->addFieldToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');

foreach ($orderCollection as $_order){
    $shipping_method[] =  $_order->getShippingMethod();
}
$unique_shipping_method = array_unique($shipping_method);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique_shipping_method);
```

And then you can iterate array **$unique_shipping_method** using **foreach** loop.